# I am returning a list from my function, but when I print that returned list, it prints NONE

Tags: python, arrays, function, printing

```
def f(N, end):
    if end==-1:
        N=[1]+N
        print (N)
        return (N)

    if N[end]!=9:
        N[end]+=1
        return (N)

    if N[end]==9:
        N[end]=0
        end-=1
        print (N)
        f(N,end)    

L=[9,9,9,9,9]
print(f(L, len(L)-1))
```

Comment: what  are you trying to achieve here? if I understand correctly, initially the function will go to the third if, and after that, the function doesn't return anything, try to add `return (N)` after the third `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function doesn't have a `return` statement  on your third `if` statement (this why prints `None`, by deafult your function returns `None`
) it just mutate your list `N` (`L`), if you print your list `L` you will see that the result is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return clause in the second if statement

```
  if N[end]!=9:
        N[end]+=1
        return (N)

    if N[end]==9:
        N[end]=0
        end-=1
        print (N)
        return f(N,end)
```

By fixing your code like that it should work